# File Extensions are missing from new SSMS 2012

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

One of my colleagues SSMS recently got updated to 2012 version from SSMS 2008 R2. After that they are view only a few editors in SSMS for adding different File Extensions
**Tools ==> Options ==>Text Editor => File Extension**, whereas I am able to add / view more extensions. Felt something was missing in the settings. Anybody can help to find out the issue with this?

Adding the screen shot from both machines (Both are using SSMS 2012). Any help will me much appreciated.[image: Image from the machine in which the Editors are limited][image: Image from another machine in which the more editors are displayed]

Comment: I can't say I ever had this problem with SSMS 2012, however, why not use SSMS 2017? Unless you still need to support SQL 2005 Servers; but that's a totally different problem. :)

Comment: As of now we are using SSMS 2012. This is the only option we have now.:(

Comment: Why is that the only option? SSMS 2017 is free and distributed separately from SQL Server.